# How to create a Drawable with needed background color programmatically?

Tags: android

I need to create a simple `Drawable` object with needed color as background color, but I don't know how I can do it programmatically without using a XML schema (is it possible really?). Please, tell me, I need it to do for making a `LayerDrawable` and working with `SeekBar` (changing background of `SeekBar` programmatically). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should try using a [ColorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html). It can be constructed with a color using the constructor `ColorDrawable(int color)`

Comment: Thank you. But please, tell me, how can I set Id for Drawable? I need to set "android:id/background" for a new drawable

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What do you need the id for? You can just add the `ColorDrawable` to your `LayerDrawable` using the constructor `LayerDrawable(Drawable[] layers)`. You don't need any id for the ColorDrawable. The id of the layer can then be set with `LayerDrawable.setId (int index, int id)`

Answer (score 8):

As it is suggested by @Thrakbad, you can use `ColorDrawable`:

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF0000);
    textView.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Answer (score 6):

[ColorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) will be helpful you in your case, you can pass  parameter [color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#ColorDrawable%28%29) for your drawable.

or you can do something like below:

```
ImageView imgStatus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgInfoIcon);
// Load the icon as drawable object
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);

// Get the color of the icon depending on system state
int iconColor = android.graphics.Color.BLACK
if (systemState == Status.ERROR)
    iconColor = android.graphics.Color.RED
else if (systemState == Status.WARNING)
    iconColor = android.graphics.Color.YELLOW
else if (systemState == Status.OK)
    iconColor = android.graphics.Color.GREEN

// Set the correct new color
d.setColorFilter( iconColor, Mode.MULTIPLY );

// Load the updated drawable to the image viewer
imgStatus.setImageDrawable(d);
```

above code is originally posted [here](http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/07/31/changing-color-of-the-drawable-or-imageview-at-runtime-in-android/)

Comment: Thank you. But please, tell me, how can I set Id for Drawable? I need to set "android:id/background" for a new drawable

Comment: this way you can't at run time, its better to create function pass your view id, and set appropriate color to your view.